# 60s or 70s movie with a submarine that flies

Tags: story-identification, movie

There was a large submarine which, through most of the film, was a super advanced sub with a large crew. At the end of the film the submarine deployed an untested feature which enabled it to rise out of the water and fly.

Not much to go on I know. At the time (the movie would have been made in the 60s or 70s) I thought it was great.

Comment: is it any of [these](http://www.imdb.com/keyword/flying-sub/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Voyage to the Bottom of the Sea](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyage_to_the_Bottom_of_the_Sea)? There was a [Flying Sub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flying_Sub#Refit_and_the_The_Flying_Sub) in the spin-off TV series.

Comment: Amazing! That was fast, thanks.

Comment: And a really cool movie and tv series.